# Jquery Sliding to position effect after fadeout from list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Currently, I'm doing up an auto-scroll function for a list on my site.

However, after the first item in the list disappears, the second one kinds of 'jump in to position' of the first item. What i want to know if it is possible to make the second item slide in to position in jquery and how can i do it? The following is the javascript code and html. Thanks for any help in advance.

Javascript:

```
    <script>
    var ad_refresh=setInterval(function(){
        var $target=$("div.manufacturer_list ul li:eq(1)");
        var position_1 = $target.position();
        $target.fadeOut('slow', function(){
            $target.appendTo('div.manufacturer_list ul').show();
        });
    },5000);
    </script>
```

HTML(Sample) generated:

```
 <div class="manufacturer_list">  
    <ul>
       <li style="float:left;width:200px">Item 1</li>
       <li style="float:left;width:200px">Item 2</li>
       <li style="float:left;width:200px">Item 3</li>
       <li style="float:left;width:200px">Item 4</li>
       <li style="float:left;width:200px">Item 5</li>
            ...
            ...
            ...
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to do scrolling/rotating vertical menu items into left side?

http://jsbin.com/welcome/53677

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var ad_refresh=setInterval(function(){
        var $target=$("div.manufacturer_list ul li:first");
        $target.animate({
            marginLeft: -200,
            opacity: 0,
        }, function(){
            $target.css({
                marginLeft: 200
            }).appendTo('div.manufacturer_list ul').animate({
                marginLeft: 0,
                opacity: 1
            })
        });
    },1000);
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .manufacturer_list {
          width: 800px;
          height: 40px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
        .manufacturer_list li {
            float:left;
            width: 200px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="manufacturer_list">
    <ul>
        <li>foo1</li>
        <li>foo2</li>
        <li>foo3</li>
        <li>foo4</li>
        <li>foo5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it with transition properties in css. Please let me know if it works for you

```
transition-property: all;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
-moz-transition-property: all; /* Firefox 4 */
-moz-transition-duration: 0.5s; /* Firefox 4 */
-webkit-transition-property: all; /* Safari and Chrome */
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s; /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transition-property: all; /* Opera */
-o-transition-duration: 0.5s; /* Opera */
```

Comment: Hi. I add it to the stylings of the <li>?